# Hiding or removing empty text nodes (&nbsp;) in Internet Explorer that render as "ì"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have created a site for a customer with Joomla CMS on the backend. I have an issue when the end user edits some articles it will insert a space before an image tag and then IE interprets that as an empty text node. This is not a problem in any browser other than IE.

IE displays these empty text nodes as small "i" type characters but with an accent.

[image]

I have validated the markup and apart from the odd missing alt tag due to end user edited content, the markup is fine.

I don't think it will be an easy task to try to find and change the backend WYSIWYG editor function so I want to try to make IE ignore these leading spaces. Is there any way to do this in Javascript?

EDIT
For clarification... here is some of the markup after the end user inserts some images:

```
<div class="before-after">
<p>BEFORE<br /> <img src="/images/before-after/Arm%20before%20treatment.jpg" border="0" width="170" height="205" style="border: 0;" /></p>
<p>AFTER 3 TREATMENTS<br /> <img src="/images/before-after/Arm%20after%203%20treatments.jpg" border="0" width="170" height="205" style="border: 0;" /></p>
</div>
```

I cannot see any characters apart from a leading space before the img tag. In IE this space is being shown as an ì

The site is here:
http://www.radiantliving.co.uk/laser-tattoo-removal

Comment: *"IE displays these empty text nodes as small "i" type characters but with an accent."* Those aren't *empty* text nodes, then, they have *some* character in them.

Comment: It is displaying a leading space as the 'i' character... in the dev tools in IE it shows this as an empty text node.

Comment: @ Faldinio: Sorry, I just don't believe that to be the case. It's *much* more likely that the dev tools are showing it to you wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the spaces are `&nbsp;` (none breaking space characters). you can remove them using this javascript code:

```
$(function(){
     var scope = $("#article");
     scope.html(scope.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
});
```

Change the `scope` to any parent element you want. It's now looking into the whole children of `#article` element.